# Write a txt from list without brackets

Tags: python, list

I'm having an issue with conversion from a list to a .txt file.
I have to save a Nx4 array into a text file without square brackets without changing the order nor the lines.
My code is:

```
for n,en in enumerate(var_4):
    stats.append(str([var_1,var_2[n],var3[n],en]))
```

What write command should I write to get a text file like:

```
var_1 , var_2[0] , var_3[0] , var_4[0]
var_1 , var_2[1] , var_3[1] , var_4[1]
```

...

```
var_1 , var_2[N] , var_3[N] , var_4[N]
```

Comment: Are you trying to print the `[]` or are you trying to get the elements?

Comment: Just the elements! I need the text file to be without brackets nor ". The problem is the reader of the file (not written by me) which will work only if data is saved as above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
s = ", ".join(list)
```

will join a list of strings into a string with ", " as delimiters

```
s = ", ".join(map(str, list))
```

will work if elements of a list are not strings

```
o.write(s +"\n")
```

will write the result and add a new line after writing a string

Comment: every 3 way doesnt work 
Just tried with list of numbers:

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to both the answers. A combination of both was required to get the desired result. The solution was:

```
with open('list.txt','a') as f:
    for l,el in enumerate(stats):
        string = ', '.join(map(str,el))
        for item in string:
            f.write(item)
    f.write('\n')
```

Thanks again, you saved me a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 1):

You are converting a list to a string, which will give you a human readable representation of the list with brackets and commas.

Instead you can iterate through the list and convert the items to strings individually. You can do this with a generator:

`strings = (str(item) for item in [var_1, var_2[n], var3[n], en])`

Then you can write the strings to a text file, for example:

```
with open("list.txt", "a") as f:
    for item in strings:
        f.write(item + "\n")
```

The `"a"` means that you open the file in append mode instead of overwriting its contents every time.

Or just iterate through the list and convert the items to strings directly when iterating through it:

```
with open("list.txt", "a") as f:
    for item in mylist:
        f.write(str(item) + "\n")
```